# How to display images in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table

Table1

```
Name File
ABC  A1.JPG
ADG  A2.JPG
PEN  A3.JPG
KEN  B1.JPG
```

Datatype :
Name : Varchar(100)
File: varchar(1000)

I need to display a report which displays the name and shows the images.
The point here is once I get the FileName from Table1 and then add the location to it( i.e.,for every row, my image location changes dynamically - "D:\WorksPlanA\Maps\" + 'File'

Please note that my location would be static and wont be stored in the table. Moreover I will have access to the location and my requirement is 'File' column will have only image Name.

I am pretty new to SSRS and trying to search examples for this implemenatation using SSRS 2008.
Any kind of guidance would be great. Either links of such implementation or the approach

Comment: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/reporting-services-display-dynamic-image.aspx  should get you started

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The link you provided was very helpful. I could successfully display the images in my report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the table is created dynamically and these values ​​come from a dataset.

Where is the value placed "A1.jpg" replace by a control image.

Then go to the image properties -> **General** -> **Select image source** -> Choose "**External**" and click the symbol of expression.
In that window put:

```
= "D: \ WorksPlanA \ Maps \" + Fiels! Column.value
```